# How many length-$n$ bitstrings containing $3$ consecutive $0$s and $4$ consecutive $1$s are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, recurrence-relations, bit-strings

> How many length-$n$ bitstrings containing $3$ consecutive $0$s and $4$ consecutive $1$s are there?

---

I thought that $a_n$ can be constructed in three ways:

1. The strings that contain both three consecutive $0s$ and four consecutive $1s$ and end up with a $0$. Hence, there are $a_{n-1}$ such  strings.
2. The strings that contain both three consecutive $0s$ and four consecutive $1s$ and end up with a $1$. Hence , there are $a_{n-1}$ such  strings.
3. The strings that end up with $\dots1111000$ or $\dots0001111$ . There are $2 \times 2^{n-7} = 2^{n-6}$ such strings.

As a result ,the number of length-$n$ strings that contain both three consecutive $0s$ and four consecutive $1s$ is equal to $$a_n = 2a_{n-1}+2^{n-6}$$ with $a_0, a_1,\dots, a_6 =0$ and $a_7 = 2$.  Is this correct? If not, can you write correct closed formula?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120819/discussion-on-question-by-webooo-how-many-length-n-bitstrings-containing-3-c).

Answer (score 2):

Well , first of all we should think about basic set theory . We know that all situations consist of $4$ subcases such that ( containing $3$ consecutive zeros and $4$ consecutive ones ) $\color{red}{\cup}$ ( containing $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones ) $\color{red}{\cup}$ (do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and contain $4$ consecutive ones ) $\color{red}{\cup}$ (do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones ) $\color{blue}{=}$ All situations ,i.e , $2^n$ where $n$ is lenght of the string.

Then , lets call our situations such that

$x_1=$ The number of strings that containing $3$ consecutive zeros and $4$ consecutive ones

$x_2=$ The number of strings that containing $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones

$x_3=$ The number of strins that do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and contain $4$ consecutive ones

$x_4 =$ The number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones

We said that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 2^n$  ,and we are looking for $x_1$ . If we think these like set operations  , it is clear that $x_1 = 2^n - [x_2 +x_3 -x_4]$.

Moreover , $x_2 + x_4 =$ the number of strings that do not contain $4$ consecutive $1's$ , $x_3+x_4 =$ the number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive $0's$.

Result , $x_2 + x_3 -x_4 =$ (the number of strings that do not contain $4$ consecutive $1's$ ) + ( the number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive $0's$) - (The number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones)

The rest is the process of finding generating functions for them by  Goulden -jackson . I am not get in elaborately that process , you can find explanation on the stack -exchange about it.

So ,

the generating function for the number of strings that do not contain $4$ consecutive $1's$  : $$\frac{1-x^4}{1-2x+x^5}$$

the generating function for the number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive $0's$ : $$\frac{1-x^3}{1-2x+x^4}$$

The generating functions for the number of strings that do not contain $3$ consecutive zeros and do not contain $4$ consecutive ones : $$\frac{1+2x +3x^2 +3x^3 +2x^4 +x^5}{1-x^2 -2x^3 -2x^4 -x^5}$$

The generating function for $2^n$ is $$\frac{1}{1-2x}$$

Then , $$x_1 = \frac{1}{1-2x} - \Biggl[\frac{1-x^4}{1-2x+x^5} + \frac{1-x^3}{1-2x+x^4} - \frac{1+2x +3x^2 +3x^3 +2x^4 +x^5}{1-x^2 -2x^3 -2x^4 -x^5} \Bigg] $$

Hence , $$x_1 = 2x^7 +8x^8 + \color{blue}{26}x^9 +75x^{10}+...$$

$26x^9$ means that there are $26$ string of lenght $9$ that contain $000$ and $1111$

Comment: Very nice derivation. (+1) Note that $x_j$ do not form a *[set partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)*. You might want to check them with the $a_n,\ldots,d_n$ in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach that might be useful.

Let $b_n$ be the number of length-$n$ bit strings that contain 3 consecutive 0s.  By conditioning on the prefix 1, 01, 001, or 000, we find that
$$b_n = 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $n < 3$} \\
b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + b_{n-3} + 2^{n-3} &\text{if $n \ge 3$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $b_n$ is https://oeis.org/A050231.

Similarly, let $c_n$ be the number of length-$n$ bit strings that contain 4 consecutive 1s.  By conditioning on the prefix 0, 10, 110, 1110, or 1111, we find that
$$c_n = 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $n < 4$} \\
c_{n-1} + c_{n-2} + c_{n-3} + c_{n-4} + 2^{n-4} &\text{if $n \ge 4$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $c_n$ is https://oeis.org/A050232.

Now let $a^0_n,a^{00}_n,a^1_n,a^{11}_n,a^{111}_n$ be the number of length-$n$ bit strings that contain 3 consecutive 0s and 4 consecutive 1s and start with 0, 00, 1, 11, and 111, respectively.  Then conditioning on whether the next bit is 0 or 1 yields
\begin{align}
a_n &= a^0_n + a^1_n \\
a^0_n &= a^{00}_n + a^1_{n-1} \\
a^{00}_n &= c_{n-3} + a^1_{n-2} \\
a^1_n &= a^0_{n-1} + a^{11}_n \\
a^{11}_n &= a^0_{n-2} + a^{111}_n \\
a^{111}_n &= a^0_{n-3} + b_{n-4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

A convenient starting point is also the generating function of words with no consecutive equal characters at all. These words are called *Smirnov* or *Carlitz* words. See for example III.24 *Smirnov words* in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

The generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}=1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+\cdots\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We use *[PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*
the principle of inclusion-exclusion in the same way as @bulbasaur. We denote with

- $a_n$ the number of words of length $n$ which do not contain $000$,
- $b_n$ the number words of length $n$ which do not contain $1111$,
- $c_n$ the number of words of length $n$ which do neither contain $000$ nor $1111$.

Since the number of all binary words of length $n$ is $2^n$, the wanted number $d_n$ is given according to PIE:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{d_n=2^n-a_n-b_n+c_n\qquad\qquad n\geq 0}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Bad word $000$**:

- We derive a generating function $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ as follows. We are looking for words which do not contain $000$. Starting from Smirnov words we can substitute each occurrence of $0$ either by $0$ or $00$ and each occurrence of $1$ by runs of $1$ of arbitrary positive length. We consequently substitute
  \begin{align*}
  &0:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2\\
  &1:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2+z^3+\cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}
  \end{align*}
  Putting this in (1) we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{A(z)}=\left(1-\frac{z+z^2}{1+z+z^2}-\frac{\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
  \color{blue}{=\frac{1-z^3}{1-2z+z^4}}
  \end{align*}

**Bad word $1111$**:

- We derive a generating function $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ as follows. We are looking for words which do not contain $1111$. Starting from Smirnov words we can substitute each occurrence of $1$ either by $1$ or $11$ or $111$ and each occurrence of $0$ by runs of $0$ of arbitrary positive length. We consequently substitute
  \begin{align*}
  &0:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2+z^3+\cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}\\
  &1:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2+z^3
  \end{align*}
  Putting this in (1) we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{B(z)}=\left(1-\frac{\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}-\frac{z+z^2+z^3}{1+z+z^2+z^3}\right)^{-1}
  \color{blue}{=\frac{1-z^4}{1-2z+z^5}}
  \end{align*}

**Bad words $000,1111$**:

- We derive a generating function $C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ as follows. We are looking for words which do neither contain $000$ nor $1111$. Starting from Smirnov words we can substitute each occurrence of $0$ by $0$ or $00$ and each occurrence of $1$ either by $1$ or $11$ or $111$. We consequently substitute
  \begin{align*}
  &0:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2\\
  &1:\quad z\quad\to\quad z+z^2+z^3
  \end{align*}
  Putting this in (1) we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{C(z)}&=\left(1-\frac{z+z^2}{1+z+z^2}-\frac{z+z^2+z^3}{1+z+z^2+z^3}\right)^{-1}\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+2z+3z^2+3z^3+2z^4+z^5}{1-z^2-2z^3-2z^4-z^5}}
  \end{align*}

A generating function for the number $2^n$ of all binary words of length $n$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-2z}=1+2z+4z^2+8z^3+\cdots
\end{align*}

**Putting all together:** Finally we obtain the wanted generating function $D(z)$ according to (2) as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D(z)}&=\frac{1}{1-2z}-A(z)-B(z)+C(z)\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2z}-\frac{1-z^3}{1-2z+z^4}-\frac{1-z^4}{1-2z+z^5}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\frac{1+2z+3z^2+3z^3+2z^4+z^5}{1-z^2-2z^3-2z^4-z^5}\\
&=2x^7+8x^8+\color{blue}{26}x^9+75x^{10}+200x^{11}+\cdots
\end{align*}
in accordance with the result of @bulbasaur.

*Notes:*

- The blue marked $26$ valid words of length $9$ are
  \begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  000001111&\quad000011110&\quad000011111&\quad000101111\\
  000111100&\quad000111101&\quad000111110&\quad000111111\\
  001111000&\quad010001111&\quad011110000&\quad011110001\\
  011111000&\quad100001111&\quad100011110&\quad100011111\\
  101111000&\quad110001111&\quad111100000&\quad111100001\\
  111100010&\quad111100011&\quad111101000&\quad111110000\\
  111110001&\quad111111000
  \end{array}
  \end{align*}
- Here the problem is not that hard, since we do not have to cope with overlapping words. The *bad* words $000$ and $1111$ can be treated separately. In case of overlaps of bad words the *[cluster method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* of Goulden and Jackson can show its strength.

Comment: Wow new book recommendation and new information..Thanks  Mr. Markus

Comment: @Bulbasaur: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful! :-)

Comment: hi , i saw your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728370/understanding-smirnov-words-in-analytic-combinatorics/4728478#4728478). When i read the book and your answer, i understand that we can get any word using alphabet from  the set of Smirnov words such that each occurence of letters in a Smirnov word can be replaced by its possible repeatings. For example, in this example $0$ can repeat at most two times and $1$ can repeat at most three times. Then ,if we think the Smirnov word $01$, how can we obtain the word $0000001$ in $W$ ?

Comment: Because it is said that $$W(v_1,...v_r)=S(\frac{v_1}{1-v_1},...,\frac{v_r}{1-v_r})$$ , here $v_1=(z+z^2),v_2=(z+z^2+z^3)$. When i run into $01$, we can only derive the words $01,011,0111,001,0011,00111$. So, we can never obtain $0000001$ using the set of Smirnov words but it is in $W$

Comment: however, by using the intuiton of @goodboy, we obtain the word $0000001$ from $$W(v_1,v_2)=\frac{1}{1-((x+x^2)+(x+x^2+x^3))}$$ such that one of the result of $[x^7z^7]$ counts the word $0000001$

Comment: By the way, for a second question if $$S(z)=1 + \sum_{n \geq 1}m(m-1)^{n-1}z^n$$ ,where $m$ is the size of the alphabet. Then for unlimited expansion in Smirnov word, we can find $W(z)$ which is the all words can be made with given alphabet. So, $$W(z)=S(z+z^2+..)=1 + \sum_{n \geq 1}m(m-1)^{n-1}(z+z^2+z^3+..)^n$$ If each letter can expand up to $k$ times, then we can find a generating function for this expanded generating function by $$S(\frac{z-z^{k+1}}{1-z}=\frac{1+z^{k+1}}{1-mz +(m-1)z^{k+1}}$$.

Comment: Then , what is the generating function expansion for $$ S(\frac{v_1}{1-v_1},\frac{v_2}{1-v_2})$$

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish: This is not my answer. But I've now added an *[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728370/understanding-smirnov-words-in-analytic-combinatorics/4728773#4728773)*.