# Understanding Smirnov words in analytic combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

I am trying to understand a generating function in the explanation of Smirnov words in [this book](https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/AC.pdf), in page $204-205$.

It is said that

"
Smirnov words. Following the treatment of Goulden and Jackson [303], we
define a Smirnov word to be any word that has no consecutive equal letters. Let $W = SEQ(A)$
be the set of words over the alphabet $A = {a_1,. . . , a_r}$ of cardinality $r$, and $S$ be the set of Smirnov words

Let also $v_j$ mark the number of occurrences of the $j$th letter in a word.One has $$W(v_1,v_2,...,v_r)=\frac{1}{1-z(v_1+v_2+..+v_r)}$$ "

Here , I understood that for example $v_1$ marks the number of occurences of $a_1$ in a word. Am I right here ?

Now, lets come to my main question.By thinking my foregoing deduction as true ,i.e , $v_1$ denotes the number of occurences of $a_1$, assume that our alphabet is $A={a,b}$ and by giving any occurrence to these letters, i can obtain the number of any words of desired size. Am I also right here ?

So , i think that lets say that $a$ can occur two times and $b$ can occur maximum three times. Then $$W(x^2,(x+x^2+x^3))=\frac{1}{1-z\bigg((x^2)+(x+x^2+x^3)\bigg)}$$

Then , I want to learn the number of all words of length $3$ using $a,b$, it must be $2^3=8$ , but when i look at the coefficient of $[z^3x^3]$ in [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28x%2B2x%5E2%2Bx%5E3%29%5E3), it is $1$

Is there any deficit part in the book ? I think that it should have been indicated that "Let also $v_j$ mark the number of occurrences of the $j$th letter in a word from one to desired repetition".

Am I right here ? Should we always start from $x^1$ up to $x^k$ where $k$ is the number of maximum consecutive identical letter.

Comment: Well, $W$ is not defined as a function of $z,$ so I don't understand.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "The variable z marking length, being redundant, is best omitted in this calculation." it is at the bottom of the page

Comment: @epi163sqrt i read your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728370/understanding-smirnov-words-in-analytic-combinatorics/4728478#4728478). Am i wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we consider a binary alphabet $\mathcal{A}=\{a,b\}$ and derive a generating function of Smirnov words following closely the example III.24 given in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by R. Sedgewick and P. Flajolet.

**Binary words over $\mathcal{A}$:**

The set $\mathcal{W}$ of all binary words over the alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{W}=\{&\varepsilon,a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,\\
&aaa,aab,aba,baa,abb,bab,bba,bbb,aaaa,\ldots\}
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon$ denotes the empty word of length $0$. A generating function $W(z;a,b)$ for the set of all binary words is the geometric series
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{W(z;a,b)}&=1+(a+b)z+(a^2+2ab+b^2)z^2\\
&\qquad\qquad+(a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3)z^3+a^4z^4+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a+b)^nz^n\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-(a+b)z}}
\end{align*}

**Smirnov words over $\mathcal{A}$:**

The set $\mathcal{S}$ of all binary Smirnov words, i.e. all binary words with no consecutive equal characters over $\mathcal{A}$ is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S}=\{&\varepsilon,a,b,ab,ba,aba,bab,\\
&abab,baba,ababa,babab,ababab,bababa,\ldots\}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Of course we see in (1) at a glance there are precisely two non-empty Smirnov Words of length $n, n\geq 0$. One of them starting with $a$, the other with $b$. A generating function $S(z)$ which counts the number of Smirnov words in the binary case is simply
\begin{align*}
S(z)&=1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+2z^4+\cdots\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2z^n\\
&=1+\frac{2z}{1-z}
\end{align*}
Looking at (1) we can also derive a generating function $S(z;a,b)$. Here the exponent of $a$ resp. $b$ indicates the number of occurrences of $a$ resp. $b$. We prefer to derive $S(z;a,b)$ from $W(z;a,b)$ which also provides information how this can be reached in the general case with alphabets of size $r\geq 2$.

The key observation is that a binary words can be transformed to a Smirnov word by *replacing* all consecutive characters by just one of them and on the other hand we can obtain all binary words by starting with the set $\mathcal{S}$ of Smirnov words and by replacing each occurrence of a character by one or more occurrences of this character. This transformation is done by
\begin{align*}
a\quad\to\quad a+a^2+a^3+a^4+\cdots&=\frac{a}{1-a}\\
b\quad\to\quad\  b+b^2+b^3+b^4+\cdots\ &=\frac{b}{1-b}\\
\end{align*}
We therefore have the following relationship between $S(z;a,b)$ and $W(z;a,b)$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S\left(z;\frac{a}{1-a},\frac{b}{1-b}\right)=W(z;a,b)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
For instance the Smirnov word $abab$ corresponds via (2) with the binary words
\begin{align*}
abab\quad\longleftrightarrow\qquad &abab,\\
&aabab,abbab,abaab,ababb,\\
&aaabab,abbbab,abaaab,ababbb,\\
&aaaabab,abbbbab,abaaaab,ababbbb,\\
&aabbab,aabaab,aababb,abbaab,abbabb,abaabb,\\
&\ldots
\end{align*}
We have the following relationship
\begin{align*}
a\quad\to\quad \frac{a}{1-a}\qquad\qquad \frac{\frac{a}{1+a}}{1-\frac{a}{1+a}}=a\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Thanks to (2) and (3) we can also derive the generating function $S(z;a,b)$ from $W(z;a,b)$ via
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S(z;a,b)=W\left(z;\frac{a}{1+a},\frac{b}{1+b}\right)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
and we derive from (4)

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S(z;a,b)}&=W\left(z;\frac{a}{1+a},\frac{b}{1+b}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}}\\
> &=\frac{(1+az)(1+bz)}{(1+az)(1+bz)-az(1+bz)-bz(1+az)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+(a+b)z+abz^2}{1-abz^2}}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+(a+b)z+2abz^2+ab(a+b)z^3+2a^2b^2z^4+\cdots}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

We see the generating function $S(z;a,b)$ in (6) corresponds nicely with the set $\mathcal{S}$ in (1) giving for each even length $2m$ two Smirnov words with $m$ $a$'s and $m$ $b$'s and for each odd length $2m+1$ two Smirnov words with either one more $a$ than $b$'s or vice versa.

**Note:** As requested by a comment we can also show the validity of (2) algebraically. We consider (5) in the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+az+bz+abz^2}{1-abz^2}
\end{align*}
and have according to (3) to substitute each occurrence of $az$ with $\frac{az}{1+az}$ and each occurrence of $bz$ with $\frac{bz}{1+bz}$. This type of substitution is indicated in the parameter representation in (4).

We obtain from (5)
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{S\left(z;\frac{a}{1-a},\frac{b}{1-b}\right)}\\
&\qquad=\frac{1+\frac{az}{1-az}+\frac{bz}{1-bz}+\frac{az}{1-az}\,\frac{bz}{1-bz}}
{1-\frac{az}{1-az}\,\frac{bz}{1-bz}}\\
&\qquad=\frac{(1-az)(1-bz)+az(1-bz)+bz(1-az)+abz^2}{(1-az)(1-bz)-abz^2}\\
&\qquad=\frac{1}{1-(a+b)z}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=W(z;a,b)}
\end{align*}
and (2) follows.

Comment: can you please also show  how $S(z;a/(1-a),b/(1-b)) =W(z;a,b)$ using generating functions. I see the idea that by expanding all smirnov words in S with non-empty sequence, we obtain $W$ namely , all words. But @notasalmonfish put and generating function form in its comment in your post answer such that $$W(z)=S(z+z^2+z^3+..)=1+\sum_{n \geq 1}m(m-1)^{n-1}(z+z^2+z^3+..)^n$$. I want to see similar form for MGF where each term are restricted according to desired size. For example, can we see the generating function illustration for $S(z;a/(1-a),b/(1-b) )=W(z;a,b)$

Comment: I intuitively see that $S(z;a/(1-a),b/(1-b))=W(z;a,b)$ but not see it using generating functions. In the example of @notasalmonfish , it is obvious for the extended version where each variable can expand infinitely, but what happen when they are restricted. I hope to see an observation like notasalmonfish

Comment: nice answer, i have already upvoted two hours ago :), i want to ask something: can you explain the meaning of $S(z;a,b)$. I understand that it means the generating function of Smirnov words such that variables "a" and "b" can repeat once. If my understanding is true, then $S(z;a^3,b^2)$ means the number of words such that a's will repeat exactly trice and b's will repeat eaxctly twice ,e.g, $S(z;a^3,b^2)=aaabb,bbaaa,..$, and $S(z;a+a^2+a^3,b+b^2)$ means the words such that a's can repeat once or twice or trice consecutively and b's can repeat once or twice consecutively. Am i right ?

Comment: What is the meaning behind the notation $S(z;....)$?

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish: Many thanks for upvoting. The notation $S(z;a,b)$ means that we consider a generating function of Smirnow words in the variable $z$. The parameter $a,b$ are used to indicate we are using binary words built from characters of the alphabet $\mathcal{A}=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: thanks for replying, then  my former interpretation for $S(z;a^3,b^2)$ is true ,as well, right?

Comment: wow, what a work, i wish there were an option to upvote more than once..), but i could not see how you determined the generating function for multivariable. As @goodboy write, i derived the generating function for unlimited repetiton using the generating function of $$S(z)=1+mz\sum_{n \geq 0}(m-1)^nz^n = \frac{1+z}{1-(m-1)z}$$ For example, what would happen if there were three variable, is there are logic behind writing generating function for $S(z,a/(1-a),b/(1-b),c(1-c),..$

Comment: @epi163sqrt thank you very much, it would be nice if i can see how you reach the generating function in the note, so as notasalmonfish said, i can see the derivations for three or more variable. Can you please explain your work for generating function in the note. why is it in the form of $1+a+b+ab/ (1-ab)$

Comment: @epi163sqrt thanks for your helps, i accept your beautiful and detailed answer, but when you have time for answering, please help me to understand the case that i wrote in last comment. I wonder how you find the generating function in the note and how other multivariables can be found. Have a nice day:))

Comment: @goodboy: You're welcome. I've extended the note somewhat which might clarify your question.

Comment: @epi163sqrt  why did you delete your comments about my questions in comments ? Is there anythink wrong in my interpretations about the transformation of $S(z;a,b)$?

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish: No, your interpretation is sound. We should try to reduce the amount of comments. That's we I've deleted some of my old comments which have already been taken into account. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let us focus on the two letter alphabet case. I will use $A$ and $B$ to refer to the letters themselves, while $a$ and $b$ are the variables for the generating function. We have two generating functions of interest:

| Generating function | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| $W(a,b)=\frac1{1-(a+b)}$ | $[a^mb^n]W(a,b)=\text{# words with $m$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s}$ |
| $S(a,b)= W\left(\frac{a}{1+a},\frac{b}{1+b}\right)$ | $[a^mb^n]S(a,b)=\text{# Smirmov words with $m$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s}$ |

Let us check that $S(a,b)$ works properly.
$$
S(a,b)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{a}{1+a}-\frac b{1+b}}=\frac1{1-ab}+\frac{a}{1-ba}+\frac b{1-ab}+\frac{ba}{1-ba}
$$
Note that $\frac1{1-ab}=1+ab+abab+ababab+\dots$, which represents all Smirmov words like the empty word, $AB$, $ABAB$, $ABABAB$, and so on. Next, $\frac{a}{1-ba}=a+bab+babab+\dots$, representing $A$, $ABA$, $ABABA$, and so on. Similarly, $\frac b{1-ab}$ represents $B, BAB,BABAB,\dots$, while $\frac{ba}{1-ba}$ represents $BA, BABA, BABABA,\dots$. You can check that these four groups represent all possible sequecne of $A$ and $B$ with no instances of $AA$ and $BB$, so $S(a,b)$ works as intended.

Next, suppose that you want to count words where there are at most $p$ instances of $A$ in a row, and at most $q$ instances of $B$ in a row, for some integers $p$ and $q$. The authors say that if you substitute $a+a^2+\dots+a^p$ and $b+b^2+\dots+b^q$ into $S(a,b)$, then this does exactly what you want. For example, let $p=2$ and $q=3$. Then you can find the number of words with $3$ $A$'s and $4$ $B$'s, such that no instances of $AAA$ or $BBBB$ occur, by extracting
$$
[a^3b^4]S(a+a^2,b+b^2+b^3)=28.
$$
See [Wolfram|Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B1%2F%281+-+%28a+%2B+a%5E2%29%2F%281+%2B+a+%2B+a%5E2%29+-+%28b+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+b%5E3%29%2F%281+%2B+b+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+b%5E3%29%29%2C+%7Ba%2C+0%2C3%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+0%2C4%7D%5D). Indeed, the 28 valid words are listed below:

```
AABABBB AABBABB AABBBAB ABAABBB ABABABB ABABBAB ABABBBA 
ABBAABB ABBABAB ABBABBA ABBBAAB ABBBABA BAABABB BAABBAB 
BAABBBA BABAABB BABABAB BABABBA BABBAAB BABBABA BABBBAA 
BBAABAB BBAABBA BBABAAB BBABABA BBABBAA BBBAABA BBBABAA
```

If you just wanted to count the number of valid words of a given length, instead of with a given frequency of each letter, you need to replace both $a$ and $b$ with a generic variable, say $x$. In that case, you find
$$
[x^7]S(x+x^2,x+x^2+x^3)=63,
$$
so there are $63$ words of length $7$ with no instances of $AAA$ or $BBBB$.

However, there is no utility in considering $W(a+a^2,b+b^2+b^3)$. The authors never claimed there was any utility to this, only for substituting in $S$. The problem is, since $W(a,b)$ enumerates all sequences of $a$ and $b$, there would be ambiguity when you expand $W(a+a^2,b+b^2+b^3)$, so some words would be double-counted, and the coefficients lose any useful meaning.

The problem is best illustrated with a single-letter alphabet.
$$
\begin{align}
W(a+a^2)&=\frac1{1-(a+a^2)}
\\&=1 + (a+a^2)+(a+a^2)^2+\dots
\\&=1+a+aa+\color{red}aa + \color{red}2aaa + aaaa+\dots
\\&=1+a+2a^2+\dots
\end{align}
$$
As you can see, the coefficient of $a^2$ is $2$, which is incorrect, because there is only one word of length $2$, namely $AA$. However, this word was counted twice. This problem does not occur when substituting in $S(a,b)$, because $S$ was carefully constructed to not allow repeated instances, so no ambiguity.

Comment: hımm, but how do we calculate the coefficient of $v_1^{n_1}v_2^{n_2}...v_r^{n_r}$ in $W(v_1,...,v_r)$, $W(v_1,...v_r)$ denotes generating function such that $$W(v_1,...v_r)=\frac{1}{1-(v_1+...+v_r)}$$ I think that $v_j$ means the sequence of possible values that $a_j$ can take maximum consecutively in a expended Smirnov word. For example, if it is allowed only maximum two consecutive $a's$ and three consecutive $b$ in a Smirnov word, then their generating functions according to their exponents are $v_1=x+x^2$ and $v_2=x+x^2+x^3$,respectively. See the next comment...

Comment: So , using multivariable generating function $W$, we can find the number of all words using $a$ and $b$ (not have to be Smirnov). For example, if you look at the coefficient of $z^kx^k$ where $k$ represent the length of the word in the expansion of $$W(v_1,v_2)=\frac{1}{1-((x+x^2)+(x+x^2+x^3))}$$ I have found an answer written by @epi163sqrt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056459/how-many-length-n-bitstrings-containing-3-consecutive-0s-and-4-consecuti/4191721#4191721) which use Smirnov words. I think it corrects my intuition.

Comment: In my intuition, for example the number words of length $2$, $$((x+x^2)+(x+x^2+x^3))((x+x^2)+(x+x^2+x^3))$$ $(x+x^2)(x+x^2)$ means $xx+xx^2+x^2x+x^2x^4$, then they mean $aa,aaa,aaa,aaaa$, respectively. For another exapmle , $$(x+x^2+x^3)(x+x^2)$$ will give us $xx,xx^2,x^2x,x^2x^2,x^3x,x^3x^2$ means $bb,baa,bba,bbaa,bbba,bbbaa$ ,respectively

Comment: When you expand them like that you will obtain all possible words using $a,b$ .Moreover, $z^2x^2$ will show you $aa,ab,ba,bb$ as we desired

Comment: hi Mike, i realized the overcounting when we deal with $W(a+a^2)$, so to reach the correct result, i added the variable $z$ as i mentioned in my post. When you look for some thing, you should look at $[z^ka^k]$. Moreover, another user write some comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056459/how-many-length-n-bitstrings-containing-3-consecutive-0s-and-4-consecuti/4191721#4191721). Can you please look at that, i think their comment is right

Comment: because of addding variable $z$, i think that we can find all words  like @notasalmon fish did

Comment: moreover, can you please help to understand how $$W(v_1,v_2)=S(v_1/(1-v_1),v_2/(1-v_2)$$ I did not think it before @notasalmonfish asked in their comment. These two are generating functions but how their coefficient become equal ? (I understand the logic that if you expand the smirnov words you obtain all words but not in the form of generating fnctions)

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Very nice update! (+1)

Comment: how can we expand $S(x+x^2,x+x^2+x^3)$ without using $S(a,b)=W(a/(1+a),b/(1+b))$ but just using the generating function of $$S((x+x^2)/(1-(x+x^2),(x+x^2+x^3)/(1-(x+x^2+x^3))$$

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for your nice answer and helps,but i can only accept one answer, so i could only upvoted. have a nice day :))

Comment: @goodboy I completely understand. epi163sqrt is one of the premium experts for generating functions on this website.